# Best method to connect Thunderbolt 2 external RAID drive to a new custom built PC

Tags: pcie, thunderbolt

Soon I will upgrade from a Mac-based system to a custom built PC for video post-production (I haven't yet decided on the components which is why I'm asking about this).

One issue is that I currently use a 24TB G-Speed Thunderbolt 2 Raid with my Mac. If possible I would like to continue to use it on the PC that I build.

So far the best way I can think of is to install a Thunderbolt 3 PCIe card in the new PC and then use the Apple Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter dongle to connect the Raid to the PC. Anybody got any better solution? Or reasons why my idea won't work?

EDIT 7/22/19: Now I see that there are motherboards that have Thunderbolt 3 built straight into the board such as the Z390 DESIGNARE and the yet-to-be-released ASRock X570 Creator. This may be a better route for me than a PCIe adapter.

Comment: Did you upgrade to a motherboard with native Thunderbolt 3 support? The addin cards require a header on the motherboard since Thunderbolt cannot be sent through the PCIe slot.

Comment: Thanks - yeah as I've been researching since I posted I found out there were a small handful of motherboards with Thunderbolt 3 built into the board itself. Right now I'm looking at the Z390 DESIGNARE and going the Intel i9 9900K route. I would like to look at going with the new 3rd gen AMD Ryzen 7 or 9 but there doesn't appear to be an x570 board that fits my needs and has Thunderbolt 3. (the ASRock x570 creator was announced already and was supposed to be released on July 7 but it wasn't and IDK when it will be).